# Android app shows already pinned sites in autocomplete

Tags: bug, android-app

Go to the nav menu and select `EDIT` under My Sites.

Start typing the name of a site which you have already pinned, e.g., Stack Overflow.

The already pinned site appears under autocomplete.

Yes, this is a very minor bug, but a bug nonetheless.

Comment: Additionally, I am able to add multiple instances of the same site.

Comment: Repro'd on 1.0.51. For the sake of completeness, please also include App version, and also Android version and device model (if related).

Comment: For the bug itself, here's my observation: 1) Autocomplete *sometimes* shows the site you've already included. 2) At most, 2 instances of same site can be shown while managing "Your Sites", but there is no effect on the navigation drawer; there is only 1 instance for each site you've added.